# netplan 2 nic setup

Tags: server, netplan

I have a home server with an integrated gigabit Ethernet, and a PCI-e gigabit Ethernet card. I want to have my own LAN, separated from the ISP router. I don't want to use a dedicated router, I want to do it with this machine.
Eventually, I want to have the whole home network to be using a VPN service.
I already have a (probably correctly set up) DHCP service running on the enp1s0 nic.

I can't figure out why my netplan settings don't work.
Do I need to bride, or route my traffic?

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# For more information, see netplan(5).
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
#integrated NIC connected to ISP router
    enp3s0:
     dhcp4: no
     dhcp6: no
     addresses: [192.168.0.5/24]
     gateway4: 192.168.0.1
     nameservers:
       addresses: [192.168.0.6]

#pci-e nic, connected to local lan switch
    enp1s0:
     dhcp4: no
     dhcp6: no
     addresses: [192.168.1.1/24]
     gateway4: 192.168.0.5
     nameservers:
       addresses: [192.168.0.6]
    routes:
    - to: 192.168.0.5/24
      via: 192.168.1.1
```

[image]

Comment: You have "`addresses: [192.168.0.6]`" twice. Are you sure? Not shown on diagram?

Comment: that's my piHole. I'll have to move it 192.168.1.6 once the setup is done.

Comment: Sounds like a routing problem. What does `ip route` show you? Please edit ( https://askubuntu.com/posts/1058445/edit ) your post and add the results.

Comment: You don't say what part is not working.  But looking at it, I question the references to the 192.168.0 network on the enp1s0 interface.  What do you expect this to do?  What it does in practice is tell your machine that it's ok to send traffic destined for the 192.168.0 network out through this interface, which is not what your network diagram shows.